# GUVNOR 6.0 CR3 Deploying rules and firing from a java application

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, guvnor

Below is the screen of jboss guvnor 5.5 building and deploying a package.

[image]

what is the equivalent process of creating snapshot for deployment in **guvnor 6.0 cr3**?

In other words  I am looking on deploying rules written using guvnor 6.0 and execute it from a java application.

```
public static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {     

     KnowledgeAgent kagent = KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgent( "SomeAgent" );         
     kagent.applyChangeSet( ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource( "changeset.xml" ) );         
     KnowledgeBase kbase = kagent.getKnowledgeBase();            
     kagent.dispose();          
     return kbase;

}
```

where the changeset.xml holded the snapshot url of the package.

I understand the top level architectural changes in the guvnor 6.0 or rather drools workbench.

But I could'nt find a way to deploy rules and execute from an java application.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Guvnor will create a maven artifact containing the package assets. You then use that artifact to instantiate a kbase/ksession.
BTW, forget about KnowledgeAgent. It is no longer part of drools distribution (since drools 6).

Hope it helps,

Comment: Can you point to an example showing how to instantiate a kbase/session on a maven artifact? that will be of great help.

Comment: @Esteban Aliverti: Please provide some example on connecting Guvnor to java application.

Comment: I don't know if there is any integration test. I haven't checked the code lately. You should ask in Drools mailing list.
More information about the way Drools 6 handles kieSessions and kieBases can be found here: http://blog.athico.com/2013/10/configuration-and-convention-based.html